# Bellman equation for MRP

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, bellman-equations

Bellman equation for MRP is:

[image]

And it can be written as

[image]

or the inverse matrix method, when the transition matrix is known. My question is: how the left $v$ equals to the right $v$ in the second formula, when $v(s)$ and $v(s^{\prime})$ refer to rewards sum begin from $t$ and $t+1$ respectively in the first formula?

Comment: Please give a reference where you found these formulae. They look equivalent to me, assuming some things about what the variables $v$, $r$, $P$ represent.